# How to use URL Rewriting on a htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite the URL so instead of looking like this:

> website.com/index.php/acars

it looks like this:

> website.com/index.php?p=acars

and maybe like this:

> website.com/acars

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and where you got stuck. A [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=htaccess+url+rewrite) might be a good source ideas.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example i use in a symfony2 project (i think it's the default symfony htaccess):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
  RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

  RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
  RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
  RewriteRule .? - [L]

  RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  <IfModule mod_alias.c>
    RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

so every request like `website.com/acars` will be handled like `website.com/index.php/acars`